# Delete Duplicate from Two arrays and display one of the arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, duplicates, array-unique

> I want delete duplicate array from two arrays, but just show one of array, how I can do it ?
> I want result
> [1, 4]

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [2, 3, 5, 6]
function arrayUniq(arr1, arr2) {
 enter code here
    }
```

Comment: do you want to return new array `[1,4]` or mutate the arr1

Comment: If you want to create a new array that only contains the values in `arr1` that are not present in `arr2`, you can do this: `const result = arr1.filter((v) => !arr2.includes(v));`

Answer (score 1):

As @Titus said, just filter the array comparing if one of them have repeated values.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [2, 3, 5, 6];
function arrayUniq(arr1, arr2) {
 const arrays = [...arr1,...arr2]
 return arrays.filter(a=> !arr2.includes(a))
}
console.log(arrayUniq(arr1,arr2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// remove duplicates from arr1 and arr2
function arrayUniq(arr1, arr2) {
    let result = [];

    // Find unique elements in arr1 & push them into result
    arr1.forEach((e) => (arr2.find((f) => f === e) ? null : result.push(e)));

    // Find unique elements in arr2 & push them into result
    arr2.forEach((e) => (arr1.find((f) => f === e) ? null : result.push(e)));

    return result;
}

console.log(arrayUniq(arr1, arr2));
```